# Native PWA getUserMedia permission prompt on iOS 1.16.2

Tags: html, ios, permissions, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia

In a PWA i require the users camera access for scanning QR codes. i use `getUserMedia()` to get the users permission, however, when you leave the device for a while and want to scan more QR codes, the devices prompts for permission again.

I can accept these permissions globally for the safari app so it doesn't show up when using the app in PWA mode.
However, using it as **native PWA installed from the app-store**, i get the prompt many times.

the app has a global setting for camera access, and it's set to true. html object `<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment">` then will NOT prompt the message again. however `getUserMedia()` WILL always keep prompting.

i find tons of peoples posts on the internet going back a couple of years.

I want the prompt to only show once.

Comment: What do you mean by "Native PWA"?

Answer (score 0):

solved:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,
        requestMediaCapturePermissionFor
        origin: WKSecurityOrigin,initiatedByFrame
        frame: WKFrameInfo,type: WKMediaCaptureType,
        decisionHandler: @escaping (WKPermissionDecision) -> Void){
        decisionHandler(.grant)
     }
```

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. Can you explain how the code you posted solved your problem? This looks like Swift native code to me. A PWA does not run any native code.